# Biblatex: avoid initials for specific reference

Tags: biblatex, authoryear-icomp

This question is related to [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503929/biblatex-missing-initials-with-non-unique-names), but the issue is different.

I have the following reference:

```
@book{taylor2014a,
  author = {Taylor, Insup and Taylor, M.~Martin},
  year = {2014},
  title = {Writing and literacy in Chinese, Korean and Japanese}, 
  series = {Studies in Written Language and Literacy},
  volume = {14},
  publisher = {John Benjamins},
  address = {Amsterdam},
}
```

This is the only reference involving a Taylor in the whole bibliography, so disambiguation is needless, but biblatex (with options

```
\usepackage[natbib=true,style=authoryear-icomp,maxcitenames=4,mincitenames=1,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\renewcommand\bibnamedash{\mbox{\rule[.5ex]{15mm}{0.4pt}\space}}
\renewcommand\compcitedelim{;\space}
```

produces

[image]

As these are the only two Taylors in the bibliography the initials are not necessary. Is there some way to disable them either on the reference level or on the citation level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to try setting the option `uniqename` to `minfull`. `biblatex` will then only apply disambiguation in case the names are used in a context where the full name list would otherwise look the same. An example and more explanation can be found in §4.11.4.1 Name Disambiguation > *Individual Names (`uniquename`)* of the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) (pp. 312-315 in v3.15a)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[natbib=true, backend=biber,
  style=authoryear-icomp,
  maxcitenames=4, mincitenames=1,
  uniquename=minfull,
]{biblatex}
\renewcommand\bibnamedash{\mbox{\rule[.5ex]{15mm}{0.4pt}\space}}
\renewcommand\compcitedelim{\addsemicolon\space}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{taylor2014a,
  author    = {Taylor, Insup and Taylor, M. Martin},
  year      = {2014},
  title     = {Writing and Literacy in {Chinese},
               {Korean} and {Japanese}}, 
  series    = {Studies in Written Language and Literacy},
  number    = {14},
  publisher = {John Benjamins},
  address   = {Amsterdam},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\autocite{taylor2014a}
\end{document}
```

[image: (Taylor and Taylor, 2014)]

---

If that does not give the desired result, you can also try to disable the name disambiguation locally for this entry by passing `options = {uniquename=false},` to the entry in the `.bib` file.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[natbib=true, backend=biber,
  style=authoryear-icomp,
  maxcitenames=4, mincitenames=1,
]{biblatex}
\renewcommand\bibnamedash{\mbox{\rule[.5ex]{15mm}{0.4pt}\space}}
\renewcommand\compcitedelim{\addsemicolon\space}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{taylor2014a,
  author    = {Taylor, Insup and Taylor, M. Martin},
  year      = {2014},
  title     = {Writing and Literacy in {Chinese},
               {Korean} and {Japanese}}, 
  series    = {Studies in Written Language and Literacy},
  number    = {14},
  publisher = {John Benjamins},
  address   = {Amsterdam},
  options   = {uniquename=false},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\autocite{taylor2014a}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your first suggestion worked, thanks a lot! Concerning the documentation, you should really enhance it with concrete examples, as it is I can hardly find anything. It's roughly the same size and has the same complexity level as the TikZ documentation, but in the latter there are many examples so I just turn the pages until I see something close to what I'm looking for. Something similar in the biblatex documentation would really make it useful.

Comment: @yannis Suggestions to improve the documentation are always welcome at https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues. I don't think a general overhaul of the entire documentation is going to happen anytime soon, but there are concrete suggestions to improve certain bits of the documentation, I'm sure that will be considered. For `uniquename` there is actually a set of examples in the documentation, so I think one of the biggest problem is searchability/"findability": Usually I can find the relevant section of the manual if I already know what to do, because I can search for the right terms.